# How should I design my Android App UI (Adobe PhotoShop, Fireworks, Illustrator, Indesign) and how can I implement them into my Xamarin Android app?

Tags: user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.android, ui-design, fireworks

I am new to designing Android Apps, and after having spent months at war with Android Studio's designer and Visual Studio's designer for Xamarin, I am here looking for better ways to manage my designs.

I have heard of people using Adobe Fireworks to design their apps' UI, but how do you Incorporate that into the Xamarin project?

Any recommendation on which method to use while designing? Photoshop, Fireworks, Illustrator, or Indesign.

Edit: The design is not for prototyping. It will be the final design to be used by the app. I have the designs on paper, but I find Xamarin's Designer to be a total nightmare to use with its long render times and sluggish response.

Please assist me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have found nothing beats a piece of paper and a pencil for initial sketches to work out what you actually want your app to do. After that any drawing package will let you make more formal wireframes (PowerPoint, Fireworks, gliffy...) then you can move to Xamarin with a much clearer understanding on your UI. Hope this helps.

Comment: I apologise. My question is not clear. I already have the designs on paper. The issue is that the Xamarin Designer is sluggish and a nightmare to use. So I was trying to use another application such as PhotoShop, or Fireworks to do the design and then use them in xamarin